# show progress in progress tag fetched from database

Tags: php, javascript

This following is my javascript code. I want it to show the stored progress fetched from the database and add further progress on completion of task in the shown progress.

```
$(function() {
    $("#prog").progressbar({

        value: 0,
        max: 96,
       textFormat: "fraction",

    });

    $(".box").on("change", function() {
        var total = 0;

        $(".box:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
            document.getElementById("e1").value= total; 
            if(total < 96){
            document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML=total+"%";}else{
            document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML="100%";
            }
            e1.innerHTML = e1.innerHTML +"<input type='hidden' name='seb' value="+total+">";
        });

        $("#prog").progressbar("value", total);
    });

});
```

Comment: i edited....as   $(function() {
$("#prog").progressbar({
var a = document.getElementById("chap1").value;
document.getElementById("prog").value =a;     is it right way to do it ??